# Accessing Google Analytics Attribution Beta API

Tags: google-analytics-api

Is there a way to programmatically access the Google Analytics Attribution project?

As far as I know this is not part of the Bigquery GA export. And it doesn't seem to be part of GA API.

See attached picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtJSR.png)